# How to assign value of hidden parameter to another parameter in ssrs?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have one parameter which contains list of employers in dropdown. Depending upon employer selection i want to auto populate a textbox with certain data. To do this i have taken one more dropdown parameter which gets populated with data on employer selection and which in turn populates the textbox with data. Now i want to hide this intermediate dropdown. How do i do that?

Comment: Why do you need the intermediate dropdown? In theory, if you assign it a default value then you can eliminate the need for selecting anything in there.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the parameter properties. In the General section at the bottom is the parameter visibility options. Set it to Hidden. This will allow you to still use the parameter, but it will not show up at the top when you want to view the report.
[image]